# iPhone scroll not working

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css, scroll

I have cleared all "overflow: hidden" css from DIVs throughout the mobile site, however I still ccannot get the mobile site to scroll.

www.thesedaysweare.com/mobile (it scrolls on normal browsers, internet explorer for the phone, but not on iOS).

I believe adding:

```
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

to a container div should work, however no matter what I try it wont. Anyone fancy having a quick look at the code to tell me which div I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I notice there’s a JavaScript call at the end of the page, `skrollr.init`. Could that be doing something on iPhone that it doesn’t do on other browsers?

Comment: YOU ARE A BEAUTIFUL MAN.

Thank you.